# Showing the last entered message

Tags: php

I want to print the last message that was added to the db. I wanted to do this by print the last greatest id but it does not work. It doenst give me any errors and I cant figure out why it is not working.

Maybe there is a logical error as I am pretty new to coding.

```
    <?php
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");
      if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
      }

      $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT message FROM guestbook WHERE MAX('id')");          
       print '<div>' . '<p>' . 'Inhalt ihrer Nachricht:' .'</p>' . '</div>';
       print '<div id="textbox">' . '<div class="guestcontent">' . '<p>' .  $res['message'] . '</p>' . '</div>' . '</div>' . '<br>';
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `order by desc`. The `ORDER BY` keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns. and `DESC` keyword is use for sorting column in DESCENDING order. which means the last entry print first and `LIMIT 1` is use for fetching only one row i.e the last inserted one.

`SELECT message FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Nice, after adding $row = $res->fetch_assoc(); and changing $res['message'] to $row it worked. thx.

Comment: Glad to know it works. You can accept my answer in that case.

Comment: You got accepted now, as you were the first here. @urfusion

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Assuming that you have `id` as auto-increment field, the highest value of this field will be the latest one.

Applying `LIMIT 1` so that only one latest value should be returned.

[ORDER BY Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this request :

```
SELECT message FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Working, too! Thanks a lot.